# photon polarization, uncertainty in Energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, visible-light, wavefunction, polarization

A beam of red light is sent along the $z$ axis through a polaroid filter that passes only $x$ polarized light. The beam is initially polarized at $30$°, and the total energy is $10$ Joules. Estimate the fluctuations in the energy of the beam.

After it passes the polaroid, the quantum state will collapse into $\vert\psi\rangle =\vert H\rangle$. And the energy will be $5\sqrt{3}J$, but how can I find the fluctuation? I have tried to use the uncertainty principle without success.

Based on the comments, how is the Poisson distribution for the process?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_polarization#Uncertainty_principle or at least I'd guess that's what the question is getting at.

Comment: @JohnRennie or possibly the Poisson uncertainty, if he sticks with the photon-particle approach.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first assume a (fictitious) beam carrying precisely $n$ photons at wavelength $\lambda$. The energy $E=nhc/\lambda$, where $h$ is the Planck constant and $c$ is the velocity of light, of such a beam would be fixed. In other words, such a beam would not exhibit any energy fluctuations. 
Apart from the fact it would make the answer to this question trivial ( $\Delta E = 0$), 
such light beams are anyway not commonplace as producing them experimentally is quite challenging. (Quantum-mechanically, the state of the beam is a $n$-photon Fock state, represented by $|n\rangle$).

Therefore, it is likely that in the question, the photon number of the beam is described by some kind of probability distribution. Typical laser beams exhibit Poisson statistics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poissonian) described by parameter $\mu$. For such beams, the variance of the photon number $Var(n)$ is equal to the mean photon number $\mu$. This implies the *absolute* fluctuations in the energy $\Delta E$ would scale as $\sqrt{\mu}$

Since in the question the beam is also polarized at an angle of $30^{\circ}$  w.r.t. to the polaroid filter, the *relative* energy standard deviation after the filter can be calculated as $\Delta E/\langle E \rangle = \cos^2(\pi/6) \times \sqrt{hc/\langle E \rangle \lambda}$ where $\langle E \rangle = 10$J is the given average energy of the beam. 
Note that the question is incomplete because $\lambda$ is not precisely stated; it only says a beam of *red* light.

Comment: You should say $\sqrt{\mu}$; $\sqrt{E}$ doesn't really have the correct units.

Comment: ...and, as a nitpick, you need to say something the kind of state the light is in to use this approach. "A beam carrying precisely n photonst" implies a number state (Fock state), with no uncertainty in photon number and therefore the only uncertainty in energy arises from the spread of energies in the superposition for each individual photon. In this question it is likely you are meant to assume a *coherent* state, whose photon number if indeed Poisson-distributed. The photon number standard deviation would be $\sqrt{\frac{E}{h\,\nu}}$ and so ....

Comment: ...the energy standard deviation is $\sqrt{E\,h\,\nu}$ and the proportional fluctuation is of the order of $\sqrt{\frac{h\,\nu}{E}}$, which, at everyday energies, is fantastically small.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance : Ehm, the sentence "Assuming the beam of light follows Poisson statistics.. " is present in my answer. I believe this statement is a bit more general than assuming the quantum state to be a coherent state. E.g., a laser beam with non-Poissonian statistics *originally* will exhibit Poissonian statistics on attenuation. Another (albeit insignificant) reason would be that a typical undergrad would understand the term *Poisson distribution* better than *coherent state*.

Comment: As for the *orders of magnitude* comparison (in the fluctuation $\sqrt{h\nu/E}$ i.e.), I completely agree that incorporating that information would have enhanced the conceptual understanding.

Comment: @jayann I guess my main point (aside from the "carrying precisely n photons", which would be a Fock state) was that your paragraph reads as though the Poisson distribution is universal, even though you likely didn't mean it that way. +1 BTW

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the answer to incorporate the comments from you and Peter Shor.